# Server sent a too long line error, while trying to connect ssh through Http Custom ssh client for Android

Tags: android, ssh, http-headers, ssh-tunnel, content-length

Im facing a problem, while trying to connect ssh with custom request/payload
I'm using HTTP CUSTOM ssh client for Android.

I'm using:-
jep-asset.akamaized.net as sni
And
49.44.112.166:443 as proxy:port

And
GET /channel-videos/5g/see-a-whole-new-reality-unfold.mp4 HTTP/1.1[crlf]Host: jep-asset.akamaized.net[crlf]Connection: keep-alive[crlf]Sec-GPC: 1[crlf]Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.6[crlf]Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin[crlf]Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate[crlf]Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty[crlf]User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36[crlf]Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[crlf][crlf]

This as payload.
It throws error "server sent too long line, max length 1024"

I was trying to connect to ssh for privacy and found no another way then this.